# Multi-Leveled ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

I'm trying to replicate the following nested list:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6Gdin7o.png]

How has this app implemented this list view? I'm aware of `ExpandableListView`, but I don't know how I would make it multi-leveled (dynamic), since sometimes there can be 100+ child rows.

Comment: here is my ans it help you lot

Answer (score 0):

ohk this is nice question.
but see whenever you want to make this type of multilevel expandable listview your focus concept is treeView with ListView.
this is best [example of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518038/3513479)

hope it may help you lots.

Answer (score -1):

such a its a big ans.
here is no space to learn it, but i provide you one link to prefer it.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: Something tells me this isn't the best way to do it...